# $\lim_{n \to \infty} n\sqrt 2\, \big(\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}-\sqrt{\ln n}\big) = 0$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, logarithms, radicals

I'm trying to prove that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} n\sqrt{2}\,\left(\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}-\sqrt{\ln n}\right) = 0
$$
But I haven't any ideas how to do it... My calculations shows that this sequence is monotonously decreasing.

---

I've proved that using inequality $\ln(1+x^a) \le ax$ and double-sided theorem.

Comment: "ignore" the radical 2 and multiply top and bottom by a conjugate

Answer (score 4):

$$n\sqrt{2}\left(\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}-\sqrt{\ln n}\right)=\sqrt{2}n\frac{\ln(n+1)-\ln n}{\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}+\sqrt{\ln n}}\\=\sqrt{2}n\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}+\sqrt{\ln n}}\sim_\infty\sqrt 2 n\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{2\sqrt{\ln n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\ln n}}\to0$$

Comment: Without substituting infinities, just observe that $n\log(1+1/n)=\log((1+1/n)^n)\to e$

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
a_n:=n\sqrt{2}\left(\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}-\sqrt{\ln n}\right)=\sqrt{2}n\frac{\ln(n+1)-\ln n}{\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}+\sqrt{\ln n}}=\sqrt{2}n\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}+\sqrt{\ln n}},
$$
we have
$$
a_n=\sqrt{2}\frac{n\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}-\ldots\right)}{\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}+\sqrt{\ln n}}=\sqrt{2}\frac{1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}-\ldots}{\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}+\sqrt{\ln n}}
$$
it follows that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0.
$$

Comment: You are right: took the denominator as if $\;n\to 0\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
n\sqrt 2 (\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}-\sqrt{\ln n}) &=n\sqrt 2 \frac{\ln(n+1)-\ln n}{\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}+\sqrt{\ln n}}=n\sqrt 2\frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}+\sqrt{\ln n}}
\\ &=\sqrt 2\frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}{\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}+\sqrt{\ln n}}
\end{align}
Now
$$
\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\to \ln\mathrm{e}=1,
$$
while
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}+\sqrt{\ln n}}\to 0.
$$
Thus finally: $$n\sqrt 2 (\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}-\sqrt{\ln n})\to 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

this is my try for this limit please

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} n \sqrt{2} (\sqrt{\ln(n+1)} - \sqrt{\ln(n)}) $$
$$ = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} n \sqrt{2}
 \frac{\ln(n+1) - \ln(n)}{\sqrt{\ln(n+1)} + \sqrt{\ln(n)}} $$
$$ = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\ln(n+1)} + \sqrt{\ln(n)}} \cdot
 \frac{\ln\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)}{\frac{1}{n}} = 0\cdot 1 = 0 $$

Comment: I've converted your image to latex, which we use for formulas, arrays, and other math notation.  It's a bit of a learning curve, but seeing the side by side comparison may help you get started.  I left at least one thing for you to fix, the variable in the limit should be $n$ rather than $x$, yes?  It'll give you a chance to edit your post to fix that.